# Is it possible to biplot a subset of PCs?

Tags: r, pca

I am working with a dataset with 10 variables. Thus, when I use the "prcomp" function on it I get 10 different PCs.

I can make a biplot for all 10 variables, but the graph is incredibly messy since there's 10 different variables. Is it possible to biplot only the first 2 PCs?

I tried indexing my PC variable as such:

esteempc[1:2]

However, that doesn't seem to work

Comment: did you try this:
biplot(prcomp_object, choices = 1:2, scale = 0)
you could choose the number of PCs using choices() option

Answer (score 0):

PCA combines all your data into components. If you only plot two of your (variable) loadings, then you are essentially misrepresenting your data, and the PCA would technically "not make sense". This is why. The loadings (within the Dimensions shown) are telling you how similar each of them are to each other (by how close they are), and how long they are, shows the proportionality.

Now to the helpful part. If you have many variables this can help.

You haven't given me anything to test, but you could try to put in `, repel = TRUE` inside your plot. This will help to stop the variables names overlapping.

This can also help, if you put it near the start of your code. Look it up. `options(ggrepel.max.overlaps = Inf)`